Add bookmark to PDF file using excel VBA
I was using below excel vba to add bookmark to pdf file. But its not working properly on new laptop. What could be the reason. It opens pdf, adds bookmark "Untitled", however does not set new bookmark. For example "test". Then it proceeds to save and close the pdf.
Sub AddBookmarkToPDF()

   'Create Object

    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp

    Dim PDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

    Dim ADoc As AcroAVDoc

    Dim PDBookmark As AcroPDBookmark

    Dim PDFPageView As AcroAVPageView
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pg As Integer
    Dim bm As String
    Dim btitle As String
    Dim n As Variant

    

    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    Set PDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    Set ADoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    Set PDBookmark = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDBookmark", "")

    PDoc.Open ("C:\test\abc.pdf")

    Set ADoc = PDoc.OpenAVDoc("C:\test\abc.pdf")

    Set PDFPageView = ADoc.GetAVPageView()


        bm = "test"

   

       'Set the focus to adobe acrobat pro

        'AppActivate (dbAdobeID)
        
        AppActivate ("C:\test")
        'AppActivate "Adobe Acrobat Pro"

     

       'Go to specific page – location of first page of a specific TFL

        Call PDFPageView.GoTo(0)

       'Create a new bookmark

        AcroApp.MenuItemExecute ("NewBookmark")

        'Give new bookmark a title as “Untitled”
        btitle = PDBookmark.GetByTitle(PDoc, "Untitled")
        If PDBookmark.GetByTitle(PDoc, "Untitled") = True Then
        'Set title of bookmark as the title of TFL
            btitle = PDBookmark.SetTitle(bm)
        End If
    
    'Save PDF

    n = PDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\test\abc.pdf")
    btitle = PDBookmark.SetTitle("test")
    PDoc.Close


    AcroApp.Exit

    Set AcroApp = Nothing

    Set PDoc = Nothing

    Set ADoc = Nothing

End Sub


When I open pdf file manually, it shows ("C:\test\filename") in title bar
